# Establishing convergence of $\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{x^2+1}{x}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I am tasked with determining whether the following improper integral converges:
$$\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{x^2+1}{x}}dx$$Deemed improper as $\lim_{x\to0^+}\sqrt{(x^2+1)/x}=\infty$. After a while of struggling I got Wolfram alpha to tell me that it evaluates to some expression involving hypergeometric functions (whatever they are - but not important!) - i.e: it converges, so it was left to me to demonstrate why.

Seeing as the function doesn't have an elementary antiderivative, it won't be possible to just show $\lim_{x\to0^+}\int_x^1\sqrt{(t^2+1)/t}\;dt$ exists, rather something like comparison to a larger function would be necessary, but I don't really know how to do that to functions in this form. I was also thinking of sort of using a reverse of the integral test for infinite series, by performing some change of variables on the integrand to get something like $\int_1^\infty f(t)dt$ which exists iff $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ but I don't know whether (a) this would be valid or (b) this would be any quicker/easier.

Any help regarding this specific integral, or further general methods for dealing with improper integrals, would be much appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this the same as proving that $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt x}$ converges since the top is always positive?

Comment: Yes, very nice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  *equivalence* of functions: near $0$, $x^2+1\sim 1$, so for $x>0 $,
$$\sqrt{\frac{x^2+1}{x}}\sim_0\frac1{\sqrt x},$$
and the integral $\;\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt x}\,\mathrm d x\;$ converges.

Comment: Interesting - this isn't something I've covered explicitly, it is possible this method is equivalent to something else?

Comment: I would be more convinced by saying that for $0 \lt x \lt 1$ you have $\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x}} \lt \sqrt{\dfrac{1+x^2}{x}} \lt \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{x}}$. Everything is positive, while $\int\limits_0^1\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}\,\mathrm d x=2$ and $\int\limits_0^1\sqrt{\frac{2}{x}}\,\mathrm d x=2\sqrt 2$ are easy to evaluate and clearly converge

Comment: 1) You can compute it just in your head – it has a standard antiderivative. 2) Any basic course teaches that $\;\int_0^1\frac 1{x^p}\,\mathrm d x$ converges if and only if $p<1$.

Comment: @Henry - this is most convincing to me, but probably because I haven't encountered $\sim_0$!

Comment: $\sim _a$ is just a notation for equivalence near $a$. This method (replacing with a simpler equivalent function) is also standard for the convergence of series with positive terms (in this case, one uses *asymptotic equivalence*). See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis)

Answer (score 1):

By substituting $u=\sqrt{x}\ $ we get $\displaystyle \int_0^1\sqrt{\dfrac{x^2+1}x}\mathop{dx}=\int_0^1\sqrt{x^2+1}\ \dfrac{\mathop{dx}}{\sqrt{x}}=2\int_0^1\sqrt{u^4+1}\mathop{du}$

And the integrated function is continuous on $[0,1]$ thus integrable.